# Using Linq with SQLite: Table recognized but "Results View" gives error

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite

I'm trying to work with SQLITE in .
However I've faced a weird problem :

```
// Start of code
connection = new SQLiteConnection(myConnectionString);
connection.Open();
myDataContext = new Main(connection, new SqliteVendor());
// End of code
```

Examing 'myDataContext' after execution (with debugger), I see it has the type 'Main' (as should be :)) and also has as members,
the names of the tables I've defind in DB (so far - so good...), but...
Trying open one table (which has(!) records), and then trying to open the "ResultView" member of that table, I'm facing the string
"SQLite error\n No such table: main:XXXX" 
(XXXX is the table name...)
(I've came to examine the structure because when I've tried to fetch records by linq command - I've got an exception.)
Do you have any idea what can cause this behavior?
Thanks,
Rivka

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the source of it...
(actually found it several hours after I've published the question...)
I'm working with visual studio and my DB file name is part of the project. 
Since I've changed the (name and content...) of th db filename, i've forgot to mark 
it "Copy Always"... That has caused the problem.
Please mark that as solved...

Comment: Hello @Rivka Licht, welcome to StackOverflow. Great that you already found the solution, and thank you for also posting it, too! As you are the one who posted the question, you will need to mark it as *answered* by yourself. :-)